# Stack: ros is not displayed after I run roswtf

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
kv@kv:/opt/ros/indigo$ roscd
kv@kv:/opt/ros/indigo$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225440/stack:-ros-is-not-displayed-after-i-run-roswtf/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-30**:
If you're following a specific tutorial or expecting something else, please provide a link to the tutorial or explain a little more.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-15**:
Please help and explain. I'm also facing the same problem. Currently doing this [roswtf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf)

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-15**:
Eventhough I already *roscd* It still says **No package or stack in context** .
According to tutorial it should display stack:ros:
**"Stack: ros": roswtf uses whatever your current directory is to determine what checks it does. This is telling us that you started roswtf in the ros stack.**

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-15**:
@ahendrix Please explain

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-16**:
@ahendrix can you help to answer please?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-17**:
It looks like that tutorial was written for an old version of ROS, and the package layout on newer version of ROS is different.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-18**:
@ahendrix can you elaborate more please?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the [roswtf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf) was outdated (using output from old packaging concept 'stack'), so I've [updated](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf?action=diff&rev2=19&rev1=18) where you're no longer expected to see `stack` output from roswtf and what you're seeing is right. Also see #q41808 for more explanation about the roswtf output.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0